# Updated android studio and got fail with Gstreamer build

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, gstreamer, gradle-plugin

Updated to Android Studio 3.0.0 with new android gradle plugin.
While buildin project got message:

```
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task `':app:externalNativeBuildDebug'`.

Expected output file at `gst-build-arm64-v8a/libgstreamer_android.so` for target `gstreamer_android` but there was none
```

but `libgstreamer_android.so` library file is already there. For native code I use ndk-build. Does anyone have this issue?

Comment: I'm having exact the same problem and I'm trying to figure it out... I already tried to use gradle 4.3 instead of 4.1, clean, rebuild, re-link the project... I guess I will try downgrade the android plugin 3.0 while i don't find a better solution

Comment: @EduardoFernando, look at my answer, please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add to build.gradle file of our android module field targets.

```
android { 
  defaultConfig { 
    externalNativeBuild { 
      ndkBuild { 
        targets "name_of_native_module_in_android_mk_file" 
      } 
  ... 
}
```

Don't add `gstreamer_android`.

Comment: I have some questions... First: It's on (build.grade Module:app) rigth?
Second: My externalNativeBuild{ } is not inside defaultConfig { }... it's on android { }... Should I erase it from android{ } and put it on android{ defaultConfig{ } } ??
Third: Inside externalNativeBuild{ndkBuild{ } } there's "path 'src/main/jni/Android.mk'" Should I keep it there or erase do only add the command with "targets" ?
Forth: What's and where's the "name_of_native_module_in_android_mk_file" ? Is it in "LOCAL_MODULE" variable?

Comment: @EduardoFernando, 1. in model with gstreamer usage. 2. externalNativeBuild in application hold path to Android.mk file, externalNativeBuild in default config I described targets (native modules) and abi filters. I hope it will help. you

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** Valery's answer works!

**Obsolete answer:**
That's not the **perfect fix**, it's just **temporary** until I have time to take a deep look into the problem.
 Downgrade your gradle plugin:

1. File -> Project Structure
2. Click at "Project"
3. At "Gradle version" field put:

   - 3.3
4. At "Android Plugin Version" field put:

   - 2.3.3
5. Hit "OK"

Accept the messages, sync the project, etc... Android Studio may prompt a windown asking for update gradle plugin again, just **don't accept** it for now...
I guess the update on gradle changed the way the builds are made, maybe something on Android.mk will have to change or some other parameter on build.grade...

**edit:** I found some clue at: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html

> API changes 
> Android plugin 3.0.0 introduces API changes that **removes
>   certain functionalities and may break your existing builds**. Later
>   versions of the plugin may introduce new public APIs that replace
>   broken functionalities.
>
> **Modifying variant outputs at build time may not work** Using the Variant
>   API to manipulate variant outputs is broken with the new plugin. It
>   still works for simple tasks, such as changing the APK name during
>   build time, as shown below:...

So, I guess we should keep using the temporary fix (not updated version of gradle)...

Comment: I've found *.so files, lying at `app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs-debug/*.so`, but dont know how to use them while building project