# Expected output file at gst-build-armeabi-v7a/libgstreamer_android.so for target gstreamer_android but there was none

Tags: android, gstreamer

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:externalNativeBuildDebug'.

> Expected output file at gst-build-armeabi-v7a/libgstreamer_android.so for target gstreamer_android but there was none

while building gstreamer on android studio i am getting the above error,please tell me how to solve it.

i tried in so many ways,i add

```
        abiFilters 'x86','armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
```

also in build.gradle(module.app),still getting the same error

please tell me how to overcome this error

Thanks in advance

archana

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/47632963