# How to include libc++_shared.so into my APK programmatically with gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk, gstreamer

Updated in project:

- Gstreamer 1.14.5 -> Gstreamer 1.18.0
- NDKr16 -> NDKr21.3.6528147
- build:gradle:3.5.3 -> build:gradle:4.1.0
- buildToolsVersion 29.0.3

  ```
   compileSdk: 29,
   minSdk    : 26,
   targetSdk : 29,
   material  : "1.2.1",
   constraint: "2.0.2",
   ktx       : "1.1.0",
   espresso  : "3.1.0",
   mockito   : "2.9.0",
   junit     : "4.13.1"
  ```

This updates produce an issue:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libc++_shared.so" not found
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1071)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1007)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1667)
    at com.kbnt.naparnik.client.MainActivity.<clinit>(MainActivity.java:103)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method) 
...
```

Project building correctly but when I run app it crash with issue

Android.mk file:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := client
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := client.c
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := gstreamer_android
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -landroid
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

ifndef GSTREAMER_ROOT_ANDROID
    $(error GSTREAMER_ROOT_ANDROID is not defined!)
endif
ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),armeabi)
    GSTREAMER_ROOT        := $(GSTREAMER_ROOT_ANDROID)/arm
else ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),armeabi-v7a)
    GSTREAMER_ROOT        := $(GSTREAMER_ROOT_ANDROID)/armv7
else ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),arm64-v8a)
    GSTREAMER_ROOT        := $(GSTREAMER_ROOT_ANDROID)/arm64
else ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),x86)
    GSTREAMER_ROOT        := $(GSTREAMER_ROOT_ANDROID)/x86
else ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),x86_64)
    GSTREAMER_ROOT        := $(GSTREAMER_ROOT_ANDROID)/x86_64
else
    #$(error Target arch ABI not supported: $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI))
    GSTREAMER_ROOT        := $(GSTREAMER_ROOT_ANDROID)/armv7
endif

GSTREAMER_NDK_BUILD_PATH  := $(GSTREAMER_ROOT)/share/gst-android/ndk-build/
include $(GSTREAMER_NDK_BUILD_PATH)/plugins.mk

GSTREAMER_PLUGINS         :=  $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_CORE)         \
                             $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_CODECS)        \
                             $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_EFFECTS)       \
                             $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_NET)           \
                             $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_CAPTURE)       \
                             $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_PLAYBACK)      \
                             $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_SYS)

GSTREAMER_EXTRA_DEPS      := gstreamer-video-1.0
include $(GSTREAMER_NDK_BUILD_PATH)/gstreamer-1.0.mk
```

Application.mk file:

```
APP_STL := c++_shared
APP_PLATFORM := android-26
```

I find note in documentation https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support#c_runtime_libraries:

> libc++ is not a system library. If you use libc++_shared.so, it must be included in your APK. If you're building your application with Gradle this is handled automatically.

I understand that it building incorrectly, because my APK don`t include library

**How to include libc++_shared.so into my APK programmatically with gradle?**

Structure of project

[image]

app/build.gradle:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion versions.compileSdk
defaultConfig {
    ...
    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            if (System.getenv("GSTREAMER_ROOT_ANDROID") == null)
                throw new GradleException("Define GSTREAMER_ROOT_ANDROID environment variable")
            targets "client"
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", 'arm64-v8a'
        }
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
externalNativeBuild {
    ndkBuild {
        path 'src/main/jni/Android.mk'
    }
}
ndkVersion '21.3.6528147'
buildToolsVersion '29.0.3'
...
```

Comment: How does ```externalNativeBuild.ndkBuild``` section look in  ```app/build.gradle``` ?

Comment: @NikolayKhilyuk added app/build.gradle into question

Comment: Everything seems to be fine, of course, if the path is correct (```src/main/jni/Android.mk```), because it is different from the snapshot of the project structure.

Comment: @NikolayKhilyuk the path is correct. Updated a project structure screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I refactored my Android.mk `GSTREAMER_PLUGINS` field and add `GSTREAMER_EXTRA_LIBS`. I replaced categories with specific plugins that using in my project and it solve my problem.

```
...
GSTREAMER_PLUGINS   := coreelements udp rtpmanager rtp opengl playback
GSTREAMER_EXTRA_LIBS    := -liconv
...
```

Looks like some plugins in categories have a bugs

Thank you @NikolayKhilyuk for trying to help me

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `targets "client"` issue. Try to remove it at all or specify `NDK_APPLICATION_MK`:

```
...
    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            ...
            targets "client"
            arguments "NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=Application.mk"
            ...
        }
    }
}

...
```

Comment: 1) If I delete `targets "client"` take this issue:
Execution failed for task ':app:externalNativeBuildDebug'.
> Expected output file at gst-build-arm64-v8a/libgstreamer_android.so for target gstreamer_android but there was none

Here is the solution that says put targets field [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47051504/updated-android-studio-and-got-fail-with-gstreamer-build)

Comment: 2) If set up `arguments "NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=Application.mk"` it produce another issue:

Execution failed for task ':app:generateJsonModelDebug'.
> executing external native build for ndkBuild /home/dev18/Development/naparnik-client/app/src/main/jni/Android.mk

Comment: Maybe problem with path, try ```arguments "NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=src/main/jni/Application.mk"```